# Code to open a UIPopoverController 

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I currently have code to open a UIViewController, in this case you have opened it before so it will not totally load from scratch. So the old data will still be there when you return. I am not trying to save the data for the next time you go in the app. Only in that session. I am trying to adapt this code to the iPad for a UIPopOver. I have tried but am not able to do it.

//without popover

```
  - (IBAction) addPerson:(id) sender{
if (addPersonController == nil) {
    addPersonController = [[addPersonViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"addPersonViewController" bundle:nil];
}

addPersonController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:addPersonController animated:YES];
[addPersonController retain];
 }
```

//popover

```
  - (IBAction) addPerson:(id) sender{
// create your view controller if it doesn't exist yet
if (dateViewPopOverController == nil){
    addPersonViewController1 = [[addPersonViewControllerPopover_iPad alloc] init];
}
 pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:addPersonViewController1];

// rest of your method...
addPersonViewController1.delegate = self;

pop.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 480);

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(790, 35, 175, 300);


[pop presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:YES];





 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the dateViewPopOverController as an instance variable in the view controller you are presenting the popover from. That way, when a popover is dismissed, your view controller still holds on to the dateViewPopOverController that was displayed.

**in your .h file:**

```
@interface YourViewControllerName : UIViewController {

    dateViewPopOverViewController_iPad *dateViewPopOverViewController;
    // other ivars...

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) dateViewPopOverViewController_iPad *dateViewPopOverViewController;
// other @properties...
```

**in your .m file:**

synthesize:

```
@synthesize dateViewPopoverController;
```

your method:

```
- (IBAction) selectStartDate:(id) sender {
    NSLog(@"Select start date");

    // create your view controller if it doesn't exist yet
    if (dateViewPopOverController == nil)
        dateViewPopOverViewController =  
            [[dateViewPopOverViewController_iPad alloc] init];

    popover2 = [[UIPopoverController alloc] 
        initWithContentViewController:dateViewPopOverViewController];

    // rest of your method... *but do not release the dateViewPopOverViewController here*

}
```

release the controller in dealloc:

```
- (void) dealloc {

    [dateViewPopOverViewController release];
    // rest of dealloc...

}
```

Comment: for some reason its crashing on the second time.

Comment: can you post the exception?
- i've edited my answer to note that you should **not** release the dateViewPopOverController in your selectStartDate method, now that it is an instance variable

Comment: I just updated my code its the same sort of thing but its not working.

Comment: If you can answer that would be great. Thanks so much.

Comment: if the code you posted is exactly what you have, then the offending line is here: `if (dateViewPopOverController == nil){
    addPersonViewController1 = [[addPersonViewControllerPopover_iPad alloc] init];}`

replace `dateViewPopOverController` with `addPersonViewController1`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need an instance variable to hold your `dateViewPopOverViewController_iPad` instance.  Then use the same "if it's nil, create an instance" logic that you had for the `DateViewController` in the non-popover code.

Comment: What do you mean by an instance variable to hold your dateViewPopOverViewController_iPad instance?

Comment: Can you give me the code for it because I don't understand what you mean. Let alone how to achieve this. Thanks