# iOS: Popping up custom UIView

Tags: ios, user-interface

I'm writing an iPad app that houses some notes and I need to be able to add a note to the existing collection. I'd like to spawn a window to enter a new note. I'd like it to be something like UIAlertView (which doesn't allow any subclassing), something that pops up, allows entry and then can be dismissed. Is there an existing way to do that?

Comment: You can have a UIView presented as a UIPopoverController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `UITextView` to a `UIPopoverController`.

Read this question for a `UIPopoverController` example: [Code to open a UIPopoverController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024822/code-to-open-a-uipopovercontroller)

Check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information about UIPopoverController.